# Sharepoint 2010: Monitor the value of SharePoint Publishing Cache / Total number of cache compactions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, performance

Can we get the path to monitor the value of "SharePoint Publishing Cache / Total number of cache compactions" for a site in sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

these counters are in the performance Monitor under the category of "SharePoint Publishing Cache" group.

You expand that group you will see the "total number of cache Compaction" over there.
[image]

Useful Resource.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934623(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: great, could you please mark this reply as answer so that other community user get benefit from it.